# Prevent Text From Not Wrapping

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project and need to stop text from wrapping in a fixed `<div>`.

Right now I have the HTML and CSS as follows:

```css
#results-container {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="results-container"><pre>TEXT THAT SHOULD NOT WRAP</pre></div>
```

I want the text to appear in the 500px box without wrapping any text. View live: http://raceforlace.com/race-results/2014-results-overall/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```css
#results-container {
   width: 500px;
   overflow-x: scroll;

   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="results-container"><pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper ut eros ac aliquet. Vestibulum at pellentesque sem. Suspendisse bibendum orci est</pre></div>
```

From the spec:

> nowrap
>
> This value collapses white space as for 'normal', but suppresses line breaks within text.

Answer (score 0):

To control text wrapping, you can use [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property.

The table of its possible values is

```
          |  New lines |  Spaces and tabs  |  Text wrapping
---------------------------------------------------------
normal    |  Collapse  |  Collapse         |  Wrap
nowrap    |  Collapse  |  Collapse         |  No wrap
pre       |  Preserve  |  Preserve         |  No wrap
pre-wrap  |  Preserve  |  Preserve         |  Wrap
pre-line  |  Preserve  |  Collapse         |  Wrap
```

Therefore, you can use `white-space: nowrap` or `white-space: pre`.